# UNIX: How to search and replace a string with a function of itself

Tags: bash, unix, sed, awk

I have a text file containing strings to encrypt. These strings are indicated by tags.

Example:

```
This is an <tag> example </tag>.
```

What is the best way in UNIX (using the common tools like sed, bash, etc. ) to search all occurrences and at the same time replace it with the encrypted value (this is a function of the string inside the tags)?

Result:

```
This is an <tag> <encrypted value here> </tag>.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why you are re-editing your question every time when I fix the formatting???

Comment: Did you ignore the spaces around `<space>example<space>`?

Comment: @khachik I did not know you were fixing the formatting. I was trying to fix it myself

Comment: @kev uhm,are you referring to the formatting?

Comment: Do you want to encrypt the spaces or ignore them?

Comment: @kev the spaces should be included :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was able to find a solution a few days ago.
I used bash and regular expressions.

Here is how I did it:

```
#!/bin/bash

REGEX='^(.*<tag>)(.*)(<\tag>.*)$'

function process()
{
   RESULT= #do processing of $1 here
}

while read line ; do
   while [[ $line =~ "$REGEX" ]] ; do
      process "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
      line="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}$RESULT${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
   done
   echo "$line" > "$OUTPUT_FILE"
done < "$FILE"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming four unclear conditions:

1. The opening and closing tag need not be in the same line.
2. The encryption function isn't a some trivial change.
3. There is just one kind of tag.
4. There is no nesting of any kind.

In that case bash, sed, awk can all be too cumbersome. You are better off using Perl or Python. Below is an algo:

1. Initialize a tag_flag to 0.
2. Read file word by word (or line by line, splitting each line).
3. While tag_flag is 0, and you don't come across the opening tag, output everything as is.
4. When you come across the opening tag, set tag_flag to 1. Continue reading word by word to be collected into a to_be_encrypted string.
5. When you come across the closing tag, print output of the encryption function on to_be_encrypted, and set tag_flag to 0.